# SonarQube Integration with IBM Websphere commerce

Tags: sonarqube, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce, sonarqube-web

I need to integrate SonarQube with IBM Websphere Commerce.

How can it be done? I have googled and read multiple articles and blogs but there is no clear guideline to follow, If anyone here has experience of SonarQube integration with IBM WCS, please let me know where to start from and what to do to get code coverage.

I have read somewhere that there is a Sonar plugin for IBM RAD but it was also written that it is deprecated now, then what is now being used in place of that plugin?

Comment: Do you need to _integrate_ or simply _scan_ your code?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I need integration to scan the code :)

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Is it possible that we could Scan Code and generate Code coverage report of code present in IBM WCS RAD without integration?

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube platform offers static code analysis, so not only is there no need for integration, but there's also no possibility.

As I remember, WebSphere runs Java code, so you simply need to check out your project, compile it, and analyze it.

That assumes you've [set up a SonarQube server](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes) (it's a free download). Then you're ready to [analyze](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code).

Comment: I got the clear requirements now, actually we need to integrate, as we need run-time analysis. Developers should be able to review their code for any discrepancy.

Comment: See my updated answer @HappyDev. Devs can certainly review their code in the SonarQube UI, but there is no integration.

Comment: I have followed all the steps mentioned in the link you provided but when I executed C:\sonar-runner\bin\sonar-runner.bat on my project it gives error and exit.....  ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock

Comment: Assuming you've got the server up and running (there were 2 links :)), that question puts me out of my depth and would deserve a separate SO question.

Comment: Yes I first started sonarQube server then Sonar-scanner, but as soon as I run Sonar scanner on my project, I got this error

Comment: I'd start another question. And be sure to detail your setup.